# Adding JS to the checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, javascript, requirejs

How to add custom JS to just the checkout page?

I found this [tutorial](https://ranasohel.me/2016/02/27/how-to-add-custom-javascript-in-magento-2/), but as far as I can tell it will add JS to the entire site.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The recommended way to `add js` is with **requireJS** ! as it is explained in [Magento DevDocs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/custom_js.html)

1. `app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme-name/Magento_Checkout/web/js/myfile.js`

   your js functions goes here **exemple :**

   ```
   define(['jquery'], function($){
       "use strict";
       return function hello()
       {
           alert('Bonjour Amir');
       }
   });
   ```
2. `app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme-name/requirejs-config.js`

   ```
   var config = {
       map: {
           '*': {
               checkoutjs: 'Magento_Checkout/js/myfile'
           }
       }

   };
   ```
3. `app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme-name/Magento_Checkout/templates/onepage.phtml`

   Here we call our js function otherwise, the js will not be **loaded** !

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
       require(['jquery', 'checkoutjs'], function($, hello) {
           hello();
       });
   </script>
   ```
4. - Clean all this folder contents `pub/static` except `.htaccess`
   - Clean all this folder contents `var/view_preprocessed`
   - Clean all this folder contents `var/cache`
   - Deploy the `static-content`: `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

Comment: Thank you, will try this out later! Is it possible to do it through a module or is it recommended to use a theme?

Comment: it is possible for the both, in your case you just want to call a js in your template, so I think it's not worth it to rewrite the module for that !

Comment: Hmm, the JS deploys, but no HTML elements load at all (i.e the checkout is blank). Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I don't know what exactly you did but i tested it and it works, recheck you code step by step

Comment: Oh, I had to copy the original `onepage.phtml` to my theme right?

Comment: yes, of course.

Comment: Yeah, I was just blindly following. My bad

Comment: quick question. Is it also not recommended to add `CSS` directly in the `layout`?

Comment: No, Css you can http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-themes.html

Comment: How to load js after the checkout page is loaded.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is the best way, but this is how I did it:

Create a `checkout_index_index.xml` in `app\code\vendor\module\view\frontend\layout`

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <!-- Add local resources -->
        <script src="vendor_module::js/checkout.js"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

Then you can put your JS `checkout.js` in: `app\code\vendor\module\view\frontend\web\js`

Comment: This is not the recommended way to add a js file in Magento 2, look at the console of your browser, you will definitely have errors or breaks some functions, you should use `requireJS`

Comment: @Prince Yeah, I read it's not recommended, but it seems so straightforward. I don't get any errors. I am aware of `data-mage-init` and `x-magento-init` but I haven't been able to implement it successfully for the checkout.  I would appreciate you help;)