# Returning and calling multiple functions JS

Tags: magento2

This is a follow-up to my previous post [Adding JS to the checkout](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/215751/adding-js-to-the-checkout), which was answered nicely [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/215880/51693).

It works fine, but now I have a problem that I want to add and call multiple JS functions, so I tried:

```
define([
  'jquery',
], function($){
 
    var hello = function()
    {
        alert('Bonjour Amir');

    }
    var print = function()
    {
        console.log('asdfgh');
    }
    return hello && print;
});
```

And in the template I call it like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery', 'checkoutjs'], function($, hello, print) {
        hello();
        print();
    });
</script>
```

But I get an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: print is not a function
```

However, `hello` function is the one that does not execute.

[image]

I am very unfamiliar with this structure, and with JS in general.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code as follows, that should work:

```
define([
  'jquery',
], function($){
    return {
        hello: function() {
            alert('Bonjour Amir'):
        },
        print: function() {
            console.log('asdfgh');
        }
    }
});


<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery', 'checkoutjs'], function($, checkoutjs) {
        checkoutjs.hello();
        checkoutjs.print();
    });
</script>
```