# I want to add custom js to the checkout page in magento 2

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout

I want to add the custom js code to my magento 2 checkout page where I need to make some changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this link for add js to the checkout page and customize as per your requirement.

[Adding JS to the checkout](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/215751/adding-js-to-the-checkout)