# Where to add custom JS for checkout page after the page is loaded

Tags: magento2

I want to add the custom js file to the checkout page. please let me know where to place the file with an example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding JS to the checkout](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/215751/adding-js-to-the-checkout)

Comment: Hi Prince Patel I tried your code but it executed before the page load. I am looking for the code after the page is loaded because I need to retrieve the product data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Add Custom Javascript after your checkout page loaded successfully,

You need to use Knockout **afterRender()** function for accomplishing your task.

By Default, If you have called any javascript code in the checkout page, They don't give guarantee for load after page content loading completed.

**afterRender()** function in Knockout Js used to perform the js action after knockout DOM loaded completed.

In your component template, add the afterRender binding like this:

```
<div class="ko-concetp">
    <span data-bind="afterRender: doSomething"></span>
</div>
```

Then in your component javascript file, define a `doSomething` function. It will receive the rendered element (the span, in this example) as a parameter.

```
return Component.extend({
    doSomething: function(element) {
        element.classList.add('loaded');
    }
})
```

source: https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html

Comment: Hi @Rakesh Jesadiya I am looking to target the city field in checkout page to block the certain products shipping for all cities. for this to achieve where should I place the js code file in the folder path.

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya:  Can you explain in deail that how will use this function in our custom js file.

Comment: This does not run after the page has loaded, it runs after the custom component has rendered