# Want to add custom js to the customer order view page

Tags: magento2, order-status

Hi I want to add the custom js to customer order view page(https://goodwayorganic.com/new/sales/order/view/order_id/75/)

Comment: Update your question with what you tried

Comment: I want to add order status UI using js to the order view page.

Comment: By default Magento displays order status in view order page, Also refer this link https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/custom_js.html

Comment: I want to add custom js to the view order page. For that which file I want to edit. Or on which path do I need to create the js file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `sales_order_view.xml` in custom theme

> app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Sales/layout/sales_order_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <script src="Magento_Sales::js/mycustomjs.js"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

Now you can create `mycustomjs.js` at

> app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Sales/web/js/mycustomjs.js

```
require(['jquery'],function($){
   // Add your custom js code here
});
```

Comment: where to add the custom js file to the checkout page after page load.

Comment: Please check this question: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/215751/adding-js-to-the-checkout or ask another question to keep clean and clear this question's thread

Comment: I have asked question regarding the custom js load after the checkout page loaded. But not answers. I checked the above link previously but js is loading before the page is loaded. I need js to load after the checkout page is loaded.