# When to use mixin js in magento2?

Tags: magento2, mixins

I want to change text Payment Method to Payment Information on checkout page.

It's need to use mixin js here?

Or i can override js here directly?

Comment: Check https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/215751/adding-js-to-the-checkout link. Hopefully this will help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case, you don't need to use mixin js or override js. You can find in the **method-group.js**:

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/payment/method-group.js

Title is a translation object:

```
title: $t('Payment Method')
```

So you can use i18n to your custom module by the following steps:

> 1. app/code/YourVendor/YourModule/i18n/en_US.csv

Add content like this:

```
"Payment Method","Payment Method Test New Title"
```

2. Check your result and it should be like this:
   [image]

Hopefully, this will help you

Regards